# Creating an NSTimer with varying interval through a wrapper method not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, types, nstimer

I'm trying to create an NSTimer using a wrapper method, so that I can invalidate it and replace it with a new NSTimer with a different interval. Here is my code:

```
- (void) createTimerWithInterval:(float *)interval{

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[[NSNumber numberWithFloat: interval]floatValue] target:self selector:@selector(scrollWrapperForTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

I am getting the following result from the compiler. Why?

> incompatible type for argument 1  of 'numberWithFloat'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be passing interval in by value, not by reference:

```
- (void) createTimerWithInterval:(float)interval{
```

But your code can also be simplified thus:

```
- (void) createTimerWithInterval:(float)interval{

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(scrollWrapperForTimer)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
}
```

Not to be harsh, but your code is awkward enough to indicate you've missed a concept somewhere in Objective-C. You'd be wise to figure out what it is and pick it up.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I've tried your code and it didn't work. I'll check again. As far as criticism, I'm open to it, but please be a little more specific. What did I miss?

Comment: EDIT: I didn't try it without the `*`. Good catch. I posted this code halfway through trying to fix my original.

Comment: My *guess* is that you're missing a solid C foundation, not so much Objective-C. That's fine, you don't *need* C, but you're going to have to understand C types vs. Objective-C classes.

Comment: I was also concerned over the [[NSNumber numberWithFloat: interval] floatValue], but maybe that was just a symptom of whatever reduction you did. Sorry if I seemed rude there, not intentional at all.

Answer (score 2):

`numberWithFloat:` takes a float argument, but you're passing it a pointer to a float.

You could instead pass *interval to numberWithFloat: to pass the value of the float instead of a pointer to the value.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you meant to pass a pointer to a float?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: It was a rhetorical question.  As Steven Fisher explained, you're attempting to call `numberWithFloat:` with a reference to a float rather than the value itself.

Comment: No problem.  I didn't mean to be curt.